# How would I write a single expression involving count, x and y that has exactly the same effect as shown (below)?

Tags: formal-grammars

```
count=0
x=7
y=3
while(y<x):
     y+=1
     count+=1
```

I'm having trouble writing this as a single expression.

Comment: This is a programming, not a computer *science* question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're interested in the following more general situation:

1. Input: $x,y$.
2. Initialize $count$ to $0$.
3. While $y < x$: Increment both $y$ and $count$.

You want to know the values of $x,y,count$ at the end.

If $y \geq x$ to start with, then the while loop never runs, so nothing happens. If $y < x$ (and both are integers), then the loop runs $x - y$ times (why?). At this point you should be able to tell what are the values of $x,y,count$ at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

As a single expression, the code segment you presented is equivalent to

```
count = 4
```

as long as you're not concerned with the change in $y$ (which will have $x$'s original value, 7, at the end) and $x$ (which will keep its original value, 7).

Trace the execution of the segment: as Yuval said, as long as $x$ and $y$ are integers, this will set $count$ to $x-y$ if $y<x$ and to zero otherwise. This operation, by the way, is often called **monus**.

Depending on the language features you have available, it could be completely described as three assignments

```
count = 4, x = 7, y = 7
```

and, more generally (if $x$ and $y$ are external to the routine), by a compound conditional

```
y < x ? count = x - y, y = x : count = 0
```